# Batch file get command's output stored in a variable

Tags: batch-file, wmic

i'm trying to store this WMIC output into a variable. when i echo VAL i get nothing !
all i'm trying to achieve is getting a file's last modification date. the problem with this WMIC command is that it returns a date as a long number and i want to manipulate that output

this is the part of my script where i have this issue

```
:: these lines are at the top of the script

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

...
...
...
...

:: a function:

set COMM="WMIC DataFile WHERE Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\folder\\folder\\folder\\container.npp' Get InstallDate"

set VAL=1

for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('%COMM%') do (set VAL=%%A)
echo %VAL%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"
    for /f %%a in (
        'wmic DataFile where "Name='%file%'" get InstallDate ^| find "+" '
    ) do set "val=%%a"

    echo [%val%]
```

All the problem is proper quoting of the string. For `wmic` the string containing the name of the file needs to be single quote enclosed and to have no problems with `for` the `where` condition is double quote enclosed.

Comment: thanks but i get a new error "InstallDate - Invalid alias verb." and val isn't set.

Comment: @Pedro, for me the posted code works. To get the error you are indicating i have to move the quotes from the places they are placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes in your `set COMM=` statement and because the close parenthesis  `)` are in the wmic command which you can't escape, just write to a temp file and read it back in, like so:

```
:: these lines are at the top of the script

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

...
...
...
...

:: a function:

set COMM=WMIC DataFile WHERE Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\folder\\folder\\folder\\container.npp' Get InstallDate 
%COMM% > "%temp%\installdate.trace"
set VAL=1

for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('type "%temp%\installdate.trace"') do (set VAL=%%A)
echo %VAL%
del /q "%temp%\installdate.trace"
```

The reason that you're not seeing an error is because your `for /f` loop is skipping the error output :)

Comment: i can see the error output.. \\folder\\folder\\folder\\container.npp' was unexpected at this time    --- when i tried without the quotes.

Comment: yeah, i'm getting the same thing, the problem is that the `()` are in the var, and you can't escape them with `^` because wmic wont know what to do with them... you're in a deep pickle

Comment: and i know i can store it in a temp file and do: set /p VAL= < tmp.txt  --- but somehow i get strange characters instead of the real output when i echo VAL. FML

Comment: much appreciated .. although this doesn't seem to work also. i get "1" as a result